# Emacs as environment for iOS development

Tags: osx, cc-mode, ios

Is there any modes which may improve development experience for nowadays ObjC (syntax highlight for method calls, properties, blocks, literals, lightweight generics, modern keywords)?

Ideally with Xcode projects/workspaces integration (add/remove files, reuse environment variables).

Comment: Will be grateful if somebody with enough reputation would add tags for #objc and #xcode.